# PHP , Facebook comments

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website located here www.sonnysgolfleague.com I am trying to integrate facebook comments on it.  This site uses cutenews for the news articles. The following code is what I inserted into my index.php

```
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<ВАШ_APPID>";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then on the add comment form for cute news I use the following code

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://sonnysgolfleague.com/index.php?subaction=showcomments&id={news-   id}&archive=&start_from=&ucat=1&" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>`
```

Which works but when you leave a comment on a news story it then shows this comment on every news story.  I believe this because Facebook needs a unique identifier for saving the comments for each article and accessing them.  Can someone help me alter this code to have it display the comments on the articles they are intended for?

Thank you,

Comment: _data-href="http;//sonnysgolfleague.com`/index.php?_ – do you really have that ` thing in there after your domain name …?

Comment: No I do not, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The *actual* source code of one of your comment pages contains the following attribute on the plugin embedding code,

> data-href="http://sonnysgolfleague.com/index.php?subaction=showcomments&id={news-id}&archive=&start_from=&ucat=1&"

– so the parameter *news-id* did not get replaced by an actual value, and since every URL is the same for *all* your embedded plugins.

(Could’ve found that out yourself, by simply having a look into the actual page source code, right …?)

Comment: So if you look at the actual source now it is correct, when I use
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://sonnysgolfleague.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div> 

but still all comments appear on all articles.

Comment: `<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://sonnysgolfleague.com/index.php?subaction=showcomments&id={news-id}&arc hive=&start_from=&ucat=2& data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>` – _that’s_ what I currently see in your pages. Still the same problem with `{news-id}`, a space in the parameter name `arc hive`, no ending delimiter for the attribute value …

Comment: This is what is in there atm

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://sonnysgolfleague.com/index.php?subaction=showcomments&id={news-id}&archive=&start_from=&ucat=2& data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>

I do not know how to store the news-id.

Comment: Are you using some kind of template engine that is supposed to interpret variables but in {} brackets …? If not, just `echo` them at the relevant position.

Comment: Cutenews has a template manager, where I entered in this piece of code on the add comment template.

Comment: Well, if the _unparsed_ variable name still shows up in the output, you’re obviously doing _something_ wrong. Have you checked that the variable actually exists in that scope, that it has a value, that your code snippet gets parsed at all, …?